# error: v.contents[30] is used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c

Here is my struct;

```
typedef struct _values {
int contents[MAX_CONTENTS];
    ... more ints;
} values;
```

In another function, I initialize this particular array with;

```
int contents[MAX_CONTENTS] = {0};

for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONTENTS; i++) {
    v.contents[i] = contents[i];
}
```

And in my main I have this;

```
values v;
newValues (v);
```

I am getting the error whenever I try to modify an element in main like this;

```
v.contents[30] = 3;
```

This is the only error I am getting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please post a minimal example that recreates the problem.

Comment: What is the value of MAX_CONTENTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v` (and `contents` inside of it) may be getting passed by value. Change the prototype of your function to this:

```
void newValues(values *v);
```

Change how you're calling it to this:

```
newValues(&v);
```

And rather than:

```
v.contents[i] = /* ... */;
```

Use:

```
v->contents[i] = /* ... */;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably intend to copy like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONTENTS; i++) {
    v.contents[i] = contents[i];
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that is what I have already. I'll re edit my question.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by 'recreate the problem'?

Comment: Well I *cannot* get the error using the sole code you posted. Everything compiles like a charm. So the error is not in the code you posted.